# How to handle the tap events in Push Notifications in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, xamarin.forms, onesignal

I've created the Xamarin Forms PCL project. I've integrated the OneSignal push notifications which are coming and showing fine. I want to handle the event when someone taps on the notification so that I can show the activity corresponding to that. I've also added the Xam.Plugin.Pushnotifications but I can't handle the tap even. The message comes and I can capture the message and play with it but I want to handle the tap event on notifications. How should I do that in PCL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Xamarin OneSignal SDK does not support PCL project since it requires platform specific classes. You will need to add your code to shared project as shown in the [Xamarin OneSignal setup guide](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/xamarin-sdk-setup).

Use the following code to handle a notification open event.

```
 // Notification Opened Delegate
 OneSignal.NotificationOpened exampleNotificationOpenedDelegate = delegate (OSNotificationOpenedResult result)
 {
    try
    {
       System.Console.WriteLine("OneSignal Notification opened:\nMessage: {0}", result.notification.payload.body);
       Dictionary<string, object> additionalData = result.notification.payload.additionalData;
       if (additionalData.Count > 0)
          System.Console.WriteLine("additionalData: {0}", additionalData);


       List<Dictionary<string, object>> actionButtons = result.notification.payload.actionButtons;
       if (actionButtons.Count > 0)
          System.Console.WriteLine("actionButtons: {0}", actionButtons);
    }
    catch (System.Exception e)
    {
       System.Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
    }
 };

OneSignal.StartInit("YOUR_APP_ID", "YOUR_GOOGLE_PROJECT_NUMBER")
        .HandleNotificationOpened(exampleNotificationOpenedDelegate)
        .EndInit();
```

Comment: You are right, I need to do the platform specific working. Thanks :)

Comment: They now support PCL. The guide has been updated: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/xamarin-sdk-setup#section-xamarin-forms-project

Comment: Where to write this code in iOS please suggest..I am handling it in AppDelegate's finished launching method but nothing happened when I tap on the notification. Everything is working fine in Android project for which I wrote the code in MainActivity. Guys please guide me for ios.